# Native crash in librart.so, all on Android 8.0, missing symbols

Tags: android, crash, crashlytics

I got a lot of native crash reports, they're all in libart.so, all on Android 8, and missing symbols. Any ideas?

```
Crashed: Thread
SIGSEGV 0x0000000000000040
Crashed: Thread
0  libart.so                      0x7a1c263e84 (Missing)
1  libart.so                      0x7a1c263e7c (Missing)
2  libart.so                      0x7a1c297c40 (Missing)
3  libart.so                      0x7a1c28f49c (Missing)
4  libart.so                      0x7a1c25d0dc (Missing)
5  libart.so                      0x7a1c2638e4 (Missing)
6  libart.so                      0x7a1c27d5b0 (Missing)
7  libart.so                      0x7a1c296ffc (Missing)
8  libart.so                      0x7a1c28f50c (Missing)
9  libart.so                      0x7a1c25d0dc (Missing)
10 libart.so                      0x7a1c4f9dc0 (Missing)
11 libart.so                      0x7a1c52801c (Missing)
12 libart.so                      0x7a1c0c9688 (Missing)
13 libart.so                      0x7a1c282800 (Missing)
14 libart.so                      0x7a1c27ce38 (Missing)
15 libart.so                      0x7a1c2982b8 (Missing)
16 libart.so                      0x7a1c28eb8c (Missing)
17 libart.so                      0x7a1c25d0dc (Missing)
18 libart.so                      0x7a1c4f9dc0 (Missing)
19 libart.so                      0x7a1c52801c (Missing)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a null pointer error in libart (the address is 0x00000000040, which is so close to 0 that its almost certainly an array access or member field access into a null pointer).  ART is the java interpreter on Android.  Beyond that there's nothing to point you at, and could literally be anything.  If you can't replicate it and narrow it, you're not going to solve this one.